# why does arr.reverse() reverses the orginal array

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am looking for is to be able to reverse an array and store it to new array without modifing the orginal array. The syntax I used is as follows:

```
var arr= ["1", "2", "5"]
var arrTwo = arr.reverse();
console.log(arrTwo) \\ ["5" , "2" , "1"]
console.log(arr) \\["5" , "2" , "1"]
```

When I output the values I am getting both values reversed. Can anyone help me identify what is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: `var arrTwo = arr.slice().reverse();`

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your syntax. `Array#reverse` does exactly what you stated. You'll need to duplicate the array before reversing it to do what you want.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with your syntax. Please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse): _“The `reverse` method transposes the elements of the calling array object **in place, mutating the array**, and returning a reference to the array.”_

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your syntax, but `reverse()` does its things in-place.
If you want to have a copy, clone the array before:

```
var arr= ["1", "2", "5"]
var arrTwo = arr.slice(0).reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, `reverse` modifies the source array.  You can first copy the array and then reverse it using `slice()` or `...` (spread operator).

```js
'use strict';
var arr = ["1", "2", "5"];
var arrTwo = [...arr].reverse();
console.log(arrTwo); // ["5", "2", "1"]
console.log(arr); // ["1", "2", "5"]
```